# I have a problem accessing csv file in jupyter notebook with python

Tags: python, csv, jupyter-notebook

Hi I have a beginner problem. So I wanted to access csv file with jupyter notebook and I am using python. I am opening the jupyter notebook on visual studio code. So here is my code

```
import pandas as pd
df3 = pd.read_csv("D:/medali.csv")
imax = df3["bronze"].idxmax()
df3[imax:imax+1]
```

The thing is I kept stuck with the error

> FileNotFoundError: [Errno 2] No such file or directory: 'D:/medali.csv'

I assume it is due to pathway problem so I've put the .ipynb file with the .csv file in one folder but it does not work. How to solve the error?

Answer (score 0):

The easiest thing to do, assuming you're on windows os, is to go to the file, right click, select "copy as file path", and then put that in the place of "D:/medali.csv". That should fix the issue, but you may find that you also have to set the file path string as a raw string to keep it from being messed up by the \ or / characters that windows uses. To do this, type a single "r" in front of the file path string, without the quotations. Just the character "r".

Another thought to try is that you may need to actually "Open" the file first, and then try to read from it. Given that you're in python, I would recommend the following syntax:

```
import pandas as pd

with open(r"filepath.csv", "r") as f:

    df3 = pd.read_csv("D:/medali.csv")
    imax = df3["bronze"].idxmax()
    df3[imax:imax+1]
```

This is best practice because when you open the file with the "with" keyword, it will close after the block under it has executed automatically.